# Append new utm params to URL in Spring Security Filter

Tags: java, spring, web, spring-security, servlet-filters

I am working on UTM parameters and i need to carry forward the parameters to landing page after login. i managed to do it by putting them in sessionAttributes and calling the landing page after login. If i navigate to another page and come back to original page i am loosing the utm params. here i dont want append the every navigation link with params.
The solution i am thinking is to come up with a filter to append the existing URL with utm params which are already in session attributes. i tried `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and overridden the getQueryString method, but i dont see new query string reflected with appended params
any thing i am missing here?
is this works? i have put only necessary code below

```
public class CustomConcurrentSessionFilter extends ConcurrentSessionFilter {

static class FilteredRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {


        public FilteredRequest(ServletRequest request) {
            super((HttpServletRequest)request);
        }

        @Override
        public String getQueryString() {
            String queryString = super.getQueryString();

            String utmQueryString = (String) this.getSession().getAttribute("utmQueryString");
            queryString+=utmQueryString;
            return queryString;
        }


    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if(request.getRequestURI().contains("landing.htm")) {
            chain.doFilter(new FilteredRequest(request), response);
        }else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is typical not to need the UTM parameters after the first page load; I presume they're stored in cookies or similar by the JavaScript that implements the analytics.

Comment: yeah. understood, just trying to understand why filter is not working technically